# Scrape data from JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I am making a price statistics project with Python, and I have a problem with scraping data from an API. The API is https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity

I want to get prices from the API, which are the last 2 values from one block.

For example,  from `[1588247532, 0, "1028606", 464, 465]` I would need 464 and 465 only. Also I want to do this for all tables.

How can I do that? Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import requests 
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity')
content = json.loads(r.content.decode())
for key, value in content.items():
    print(key)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
for value in content['activities']:
    print(value[-2:])
```

It iterates through activities and prints the last two items of each value.

Or you can collect the prices in a separate list to use later on like so:

```
prices=[value[-2:] for value in content['activities']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using print statements whenever you are not sure of how or why. See below, it might help give a visual of what is going on.

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.rolimons.com/api/activity')
content = json.loads(r.content.decode())
for key, value in content.items():
    print("Key: ", key)
    print("content[key]: ", content[key])

for array in content["activities"]:
    print("array: ", array)
    print("array[len(array)-1]:", array[len(array)-1])
    print("array[len(array)-2]:", array[len(array)-2])
```